# Getting delay to see next view controller ,see detail in post?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one login screen after that it will move to next view controller which have i have used some networks like http,json to get data from server. when i enter login username/password then if i click login button its getting delay to 8 seconds after that only it moving to next view controller.Still that my login screen alone showing for 8 seconds and then only it move to next view controller.

Here my `login controller.m:`

```
@implementation mainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _username.delegate = self;
    _password.delegate = self;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults boolForKey:@"reg"]) {
        NSLog(@"no user reg");
        _logBtn.hidden = NO;
    }




}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    _username.text = nil;
    _password.text = nil;


}


 - (IBAction)LoginUser:(id)sender {



    if ([_username.text isEqualToString:@"sat"] && [_password.text isEqualToString:@"123"]) {
        NSLog(@"Login success");



        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextscreen" sender:self];


       }
    else {

        NSLog(@"login was unsucess");
        // Alert message


        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"wrong"

                                                                                 message:@"Message"

                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];



        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"

                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                                                         handler:nil];

        [alertController addAction:actionOk];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


    }

}
```

Here my `nextcontroller.m`

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
//for search label data
        self.dataSourceForSearchResult = [NSArray new];
//collection of array to store value
         titleArray = [NSMutableArray array];


// here only i am getting data from server
        [self getdata];


        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
       [self.collectionView reloadData];


     }
```

Help me out. If my question din't understand.I can tell more about my post. And in my `nextcontroller.m` `[self getdata]` is i am getting data from server url.Thanks

My `get data:`

```
-(void)getdata {

    NSString *userName = @“users”;
    NSString *password = @“images”;
    NSData *plainData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    base64String=[self sha256HashFor: base64String];

    NSString *urlString = @"https://porterblog/image/file”;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];



    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, base64String];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

      [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];





   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];


    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSError * error;

    self->arrayPDFName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];



    NSDictionary *dictOriginal = jsonResults[@“birds”];
    [titleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" birds(%@)”, dictOriginal[@"count"]]];


    NSDictionary *dictOriginal2 = jsonResults[@"owl”];
    [titleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Owl(%@)”, dictOriginal2[@"count"]]];



    NSDictionary *dictOriginal3 = jsonResults[@"pensq”];
    [titleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Pensq(%@)”, dictOriginal3[@"count"]]];


    NSDictionary *dictOriginal4 = jsonResults[@“lion”];
    [titleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" lion(%@)”, dictOriginal4[@"count"]]];




    NSArray *arrayFiles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: dictOriginal, dictOriginal2, dictOriginal3, dictOriginal4, nil];


     NSLog(@"str: %@", titleArray);


    for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayFiles) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSArray *a = dict[@"files"];
        for(int i=0; i < a.count; i ++) {


            NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dict[@"files"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];

            [arr addObject:strName];
        }
        [arrayPDFName addObject:arr];
    }


    NSString *errorDesc;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.plist"];

    NSString *error1;

    returnData  = [ NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:jsonResults format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];


    if(returnData ) {
        if ([returnData  writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES]) {
            NSLog(@"Data successfully saved.");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Did not managed to save NSData.");
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@",errorDesc);
    }


    NSDictionary *stringsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];



}
```

**EDITED:**

```
`- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){



        self.dataSourceForSearchResult = [NSArray new];

        titleArray = [NSMutableArray array];



        //Background Tasks

        [self getdata];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            //Run UI Updates

 self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

                self.collectionView.delegate = self;

               [self.collectionView reloadData];

         self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

  });

    });

 }`
```

Comment: What does `self getData` do?  Please show this code

Comment: [self getdata]; -- may be this method taken too much time , check once

Comment: in my get data i used get method from url to show the images in collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting your data using main thread you need do to that in background then invoke the code you need (as i see is reload collectionView)
I assume that because you didn't show the getdata method code
If that the case you can use this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Tasks
    [self getdata];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    });
});
```

It's mean that your VC will show immediately but the collectionView fill after you finish load the data, you can put some old data while loading like Facebook app (you see latest retrieved posts until finish loading].

Edit:
In your code you replace viewdidload method in nextController with next code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  //for search label data
  self.dataSourceForSearchResult = [NSArray new];
  //collection of array to store value
  titleArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Tasks
    [self getdata];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    });
    });

self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.delegate = self;

}
```

Comment: in my get data i used get method from url to show the images in collection view. Where should i use you code

Comment: how you get the urls for the images? and when you get them, you can use my code in viewDidLoad or if you already have all the images urls you can use sduiimageview(3rd party api) to download the images in Background + caching options

Comment: i will get data images from one server api as in my url.In view is load how to do that...

Comment: You defiantly using the main thread to fetch the data, Don't do that use my code, or use sd_webimage API

Comment: where i will insert these line:  `self.dataSourceForSearchResult = [NSArray new];
//collection of array to store value
         titleArray = [NSMutableArray array];


// here only i am getting data from server
        [self getdata];


        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
       [self.collectionView reloadData];`

Comment: i am not getting clear idea.Please edit your answer to where i need to insert the lines as i mentioned in above comment area

Comment: yes ,but after some 3 seconds only my data are displaying....why??.There is no way to show the data with out that delay

Comment: no you're retrieving big data from internet its taking time, my best suggestion to you is using SDWebimage that let you download the image on background and use is very simple https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: i am doing that only, I will explain - i am having some images in my url/user. so i need to get that image or files to display in my collection view...Please say if i use files alone means does this delay time will be continue

Comment: if you fetching the images from the internet you always have delay, the best way is to use the sdwebimage API

Comment: bro i asked ,if i use files to fetch data means, does this delay will occur

Comment: files that already existing in your project ? and you just need to load them?

Comment: need to load them like using http get method for url

Comment: So you must use sdwebimage

Comment: download the API from the link i attached before and use it like that [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: for image is ok.. In my another app i have to display the document file in collection view.That time does i need to use this sdwebimage  or somwthing else

Comment: leave it for image as it as you said.. i am asking for document file to fetch them for url and to display them in table or collection view

Comment: Hey for other type of data (file) than Images you should use the dispatch code i wrote before

Comment: @mark if my answer help you please also vote up :) thanks